# Картинка по ширине текста

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток, встала следующая задача:

Есть макет

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="menu">
        текст
    </div>
    <div class="ads">
         <img/>
    </div>
</div>
```

необходимо средствами css (без js) сделать так, чтобы ширина блока "sidebar" подгонялась под ширину текста в "menu", и размер картинки в "ads" был равен всей ширине "sidebar", т.е. ширине текста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
img{ 
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.sidebar { 
    display: inline-table; 
    background: #c7c7c7;
}
.menu {
    background: #f9f9f9;
    padding: 5px;
}
.ads {
   display: table-caption;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="menu">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
    </div>
    <div class="ads">
         <img src="http://2017newyear.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/novyj_god.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В это случае картинка получается больше текста, есть текст короткий. А она должна по ширине быть как текст.

Comment: @Денис Обновил, но тут минус текст ниже картинки получается)

Comment: а как тепеть текст наверх вынести?)

Answer (score 1):

Вам понадобится свойство `min-content` для обертки, `width: 100%` для изображения и `white-space: nowrap` для меню.

```css
.sidebar {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1px;
  width: min-content;
}

.sidebar + .sidebar {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.menu {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

.ads {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.ads img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="menu">
    короткий текст
  </div>
  <div class="ads">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="menu">
    текст, который немного длиннее предыдущего, и больше, чем картинка в длину
  </div>
  <div class="ads">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А теперь загляните [сюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) :)

Comment: @Birdy это моя любимая страница.